# Error running ./gradlew clean deployNodes

Tags: corda

I have recently moved an enterprise CorDapp to a different machine running Ubuntu. I have install all the correct dependencies as described in the docs. When I initially run ./gradlew clean deployNodes, everything builds fine. However, when I do subsequent builds, I keep getting the error:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':cordapp-source:deployNodes'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in /home/ubuntu/cordapp/cordapp-source/build/nodes/Node1/logs.
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.generateNodeInfo(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:112)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.access$generateNodeInfo(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:71)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion$generateNodeInfos$1$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:95)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion$generateNodeInfos$1$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:71)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:140)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:152)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:32)
        Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in /home/ubuntu/cordapp/cordapp-source/build/nodes/Node2/logs.
                at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.generateNodeInfo(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:112)
                at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.access$generateNodeInfo(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:71)
                at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion$generateNodeInfos$1$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:95)
                at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion$generateNodeInfos$1$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:71)
                at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:140)
                at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt)
                at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:152)
                at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:32)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Furthermore, the log files for the nodes are mostly empty and don't give any clue as to what is going on. Initially I thought it may be to do with heap size as this new machine has 8 cores but I don't get any 'out of memory' errors. Any suggestions as to where to look would be greatly appreciated!

Below are the build.gradle files I am using:

In build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.corda_release_distribution = 'com.r3.corda'
    ext.corda_release_version = '3.1'
    ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version = '4.0.25'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'
    ext.junit_version = '4.12'

    ext.okhttp_version = '3.5.0'
    ext.commons_validator_version = '1.4.1'
    ext.joda_version = '2.9.9'
    ext.aws_java_sdk_version = '1.11.228'
    ext.apache_tika_version = '1.11'
    ext.postgresql_version = '42.2.2'
    ext.rabbitmq_amqp_version = '3.3.4'
    ext.spring_boot_version = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
    ext.spring_boot_gradle_plugin_version = '2.0.2.RELEASE'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:cordapp:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:cordformation:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:quasar-utils:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$spring_boot_gradle_plugin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

In src/build.grade:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordapp'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils'

jar.baseName = "test-ledger"

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir "../config/dev"
        }
    }
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir "../config/test"
        }
    }
    integrationTest {
        kotlin {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integration-test/kotlin')
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "junit:junit:$junit_version"

    // Corda integration dependencies
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_distribution:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_distribution:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_distribution:corda-jackson:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_distribution:corda-rpc:$corda_release_version"
    cordaRuntime "$corda_release_distribution:corda:$corda_release_version"

    testCompile "$corda_release_distribution:corda-node-driver:$corda_release_version"

    // CorDapp dependencies
    cordapp "$corda_release_distribution:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"

    compile "org.postgresql:postgresql:$postgresql_version"
    compile "commons-validator:commons-validator:$commons_validator_version"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp_version"
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:$joda_version"
    compile "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:$aws_java_sdk_version"
    compile "org.apache.tika:tika-core:$apache_tika_version"
    compile "com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:$rabbitmq_amqp_version"
}

task integrationTest(type: Test, dependsOn: []) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        languageVersion = "1.1"
        apiVersion = "1.1"
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        javaParameters = true   // Useful for reflection.
    }
}


task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    directory "./build/nodes"
    node {
        name "O=Notary,L=Sydney,C=AU"
        notary = [validating : false]
        p2pPort 10002
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10003")
            adminAddress("localhost:10043")
        }
        cordapps = ["$corda_release_distribution:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
    }
    node {
        name "O=Node1,L=Sydney,C=AU"
        p2pPort 10005
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10006")
            adminAddress("localhost:10046")
        }
        cordapps = ["$corda_release_distribution:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
    node {
        name "O=Node2,L=Sydney,C=AU"
        p2pPort 10008
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10009")
            adminAddress("localhost:10049")
        }
        cordapps = ["$corda_release_distribution:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
}
```

Below is the only change that I make to the build.gradle file to shift from Enterprise to Open Source which runs as expected (I can keep running `./gradlew clean deployNodes`).

```
ext.corda_release_distribution = 'net.corda'
ext.corda_release_version = '3.2-corda'
ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version = '3.1.0'
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
ext.junit_version = '4.12'
ext.quasar_version = '0.7.9'
```

Comment: Can you run `java -version` and see what version you have installed?

Comment: Below is the output:
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: I have also tried provisioning a new server just incase I had anything strange hanging around from the OS version (I was running the OS version no problem on the same setup).

Comment: Just to confirm that it is not anything I have installed, I have switch back to building with the OS version of Corda and everything seems to be running fine.

Comment: Can you post the `build.gradle` file you are using?

Comment: The app is based off the release-enterprise-V3 branch of the cordapp-example repo. I have added in the `build.gradle` file I am using to the question.

Comment: There will be another `build.gradle` where `deployNodes` is defined. Can you post that too?

Comment: Done. If it is any help, when the app does build the first time, I can update the nodes subsequently. Only when I run `./gradlew clean deployNodes` or `./gradlew deployNodes` again does it cause an error. I have also been running on OS today which uses the exact same build.gradle files except for the small changes highlighted in the question and I have had no issues.

Comment: I should have done this initially but i tried the same process using the cordapp-example-app on the release-enterprise-v3 branch and was able reproduce the error. Would it help to provide more info regarding the VM specs I am using?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the the "clean" task from ./gradlew clean build

Comment: Thanks for the response. I still seem to be getting the same error after removing the clean param.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Gradle are you using? We have noticed that unless you are using 4.8 or 4.9 the build fails. You may try to see what your Gradle wrapper is specifying.

Comment: I have upgraded to 4.9 but still seem to be getting the same issue. It builds the first time but any builds after that fail.